# Why is my table not displaying with a border?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-webpages

I amended my Site.css file, which is referenced by _SiteLayout.cshtml, to try to give table contents a border:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin-top: 0.75em;

    /* added below 4/23/2013 and commented out: border: 0 none; */
    border-color: #600;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}

. . .

td {
    padding: 0.25em 2em 0.25em 0em;

    /* added below 4/23/2013 and commented out: border: 0 none;*/
    border-color: #600;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: #FFC;
}
```

My table displays no border, though...why not?

### UPDATE

Okay, now, after trying to add borders to the table, all of a sudden the jQuery isn't working any more again. So here's the scoop:

_SiteLayout.cshtml references the .css file:

```
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

In that file I now have:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin-top: 0.75em;

    /* added below 4/23/2013 and commented out: border: 0 none; 
    border-color: #600;
    border-width: 0 0 2px 2px;
    border-style: solid;*/
    border: 1px solid #600;
}

td {
    padding: 0.25em 2em 0.25em 0em;

    border:1px solid #600;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: #FFC;
}
```

(Ellipsis to indicate there are other tags between table and td elided to avoid confusion)

My entire Default.cshtml is:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/_PlatypusLayout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "Home Page";
}
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Get SSCSSETUP.XML" />
        <div id="Platypus_Setup">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" id="submit2" value="Get PlatypusSETUP_000002.XML" />
        <div id="Platypus_Setup2">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" id="submit3" value="Get PlatypusSETUP_000003.XML" />
        <div id="Platypus_Setup3">
        </div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#submit').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "DuckbillSETUP.XML",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function (PlatypusSetupRec) {
                    var Platypussetup = "<table><thead><th>Platypus Number</th><th>Platypus Name</th></thead>";
                    $(PlatypusSetupRec).find('Platypus').each(function () {
                        var PlatypusNum = $(this).find('PlatypusNumber').text();
                        var PlatypusName = $(this).find('PlatypusName').text();
                        Platypussetup += "<tr>";
                        Platypussetup += "<td>" + PlatypusNum + "</td>";
                        Platypussetup += "<td>" + PlatypusName + "</td>";
                        Platypussetup += "</tr>";
                    });
                    Platypussetup += "</table>";
                    $('#Platypus_Setup').append(Platypussetup);
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

The table *was* displaying on clicking the first button, but either something with changing Site.css or because I pressed Ctrl+R in Chrome has now caused the click handler to go deaf or become unhooked or otherwise malfunctional somehow...

Comment: Is the `. . .` actually part of your CSS file?  Your code appears to work as is:  http://tinker.io/13ca8

Comment: It is working see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MtVC9/) so as @cimmanon said `. . .` can be the problem.

Comment: The bizarre thing is now I changed 1px to 2px (didn't quite want the 10), but after hitting Ctrl+R (Chrome), the button click event / jQuery code won't even work any more, apparently - now *nothing* is displaying...

Comment: @ClayShannon Check your console log for js errors.

Comment: @Fallup: Do you mean in Firebug? I see no such tool in VS2012.

Comment: The Console tab in Firebug tells me, "ReferenceError: $ is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

$(document).ready(function () {"

What happened - it lost track of jQuery, or what?

Comment: @ClayShannon Well this often happens when you include jQuery.js **after** your script, so check the import order. And yes I meant the console in Firebug / chrome / ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "ReferenceError: $ is not defined [Break On This Error]...

This indicates that your script doesn't know what `$` is. There are 2 possible problems :

1. You didn't import jQuery (less likely)
2. You imported the **jQuery.js** after your actual script.

Check the import order of your files: jQuery first, then your script.

Comment: See my comment above after your clue; actually, I had one version included in my project, and a different version being referenced in _SiteLayout.cshtml.

Comment: @ClayShannon Oh, pretty tricky indeed. Anyway glad I could help a bit.

Answer (score 3):

If the 3 dots between table and td style definition appear also in your code they could be the reason.

Comment: No, those ellipsis dots are just to indicate that there's other stuff between the two tags.

Comment: @ClayShannon But the border is working properly otherwise [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MtVC9/) so problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Aha! I had updated my jQuery and jQuery-UI via NuGet, and, although the .js files had been updated in my Scripts folder, the references in _SiteLayout.cshtml still references the old libraries, which had been replaced. I find it odd that: (1) that didn't generate an err msg, or at least a warning, and (2) the old references were not updated in _SiteLayout.cshtlm when I "NuGot" the latest jQuery and jQuery-UI. So, after updating those references, it's all working now.

Answer (score 1):

try writing it like this instead:

border: 1px solid #600;

Answer (score 1):

Try `border:1px solid #600;` instead of what you currently have.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agPAV/)

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr><td>Test</td></tr>
<tr><td>Test</td></tr>
<tr><td>Test</td><td>Test 2</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin-top: 0.75em;
    border: 1px solid #600;
}

td {
    padding: 0.25em 2em 0.25em 0em;
    border: 1px solid #600;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: #FFC;
}
```

Comment: Actually OPs current solution works too see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MtVC9/). Only possible problem can be the `...` as others mentioned.

Comment: I thought something was fishy when I removed the . . . and it worked. I thought it was an ellipsis!